# Set object into Request in NodeJS

Tags: node.js

I'd like to set in Request an object that contains all options on my web interface... This object have to be accessible in all views... And it doesn't work with my code below...

```js
fs.readFile(optionFile, 'utf8', function (err, data) {
  if (err) throw err;
  var options = JSON.parse(data);
  request.options = options;
});
```

```html
<title><%-request.options.title%></title>
```

**EDIT #1**

And I don't want to do that kind of thing :

```js
response.render('myview', {request: request});
```

**EDIT #2**

```js
exports.locals = function(app){
  app.use(function(request, response, next){
    fs.readFile('./configs/options.json', 'utf8', function (err, data) {
      if (err) throw err;
      var options = JSON.parse(data);
      response.locals.options = options;
    });
    response.locals.request = request;
    response.locals.path = url.parse(request.url).pathname;
    response.locals._ = _;
    next();
  });
};
```

```html
<title><%- options.title %></title>
```

Comment: You are setting object correctly into request object. How are you passing it to template?

Comment: See edit #1 above... I don't want to pass Request each times in my view...

Comment: Your **EDIT #2** contains an error. You're calling `next()` not waiting for `fs.readFile` callback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to pass some data to all your templates, you should use either [`app.locals`](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.locals) or [`res.locals`](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.locals).

`app.locals` allows you to define a global set of local variables for all your templates, while 
`res.locals` allows you so bind local variables to your request in an express middleware:

```js
app = express();
app.locals.options = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(optionFile, 'utf8'));
```

Then you'll be able to use them in your EJS template:

```html
<title><%- options.title %></title>
```

Comment: Ok but how to see datas in my view? `<%-response.locals.options%>` ?

Comment: They should be accessible by name (e.g. `options`). What is your template engine?

Comment: My template engine is EJS.

Comment: Or you can just set app.locals.title and access title directly